# How to include jsonpipe in web project

Tags: javascript, html

I try to use library: https://github.com/eBay/jsonpipe

```
<head>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eBay/jsonpipe/master/jsonpipe.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
   jsonpipe.flow(window.location.origin + "/api/v1/search?text=" + text, {
     ...  
   }
</script>
</body>
```

But it gives me

> jsonpipe is not defined

How to include this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the developer tools in your browser and look at the console.

> Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eBay/jsonpipe/master/jsonpipe.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

raw.githubusercontent.com is not a CDN. It is not configured to host JavaScript for third-party (or any) websites.

Host the JS file yourself or find a real CDN that does host it.